# Regex replaceAll on a string

Tags: java, regex

Lets assume I have a string:

asdf/dfa/fds?adsf

I want to be able to get the string: asdf?adsf

So essentially I want to parse out everything from the first '/' to the '?'.

I tried experimenting with it (see example below) but I couldn't get it to work:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\/([?]*)", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
replaceAll("/[^?]*", "")
```

`/[^?]*` will match first `/` and all `non-?` characters after it.

Answer (score 2):

You should change it to this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("/.*(?=\\?)", "");
```

`(?=\\?)` is a look-ahead that means "the next character is a literal `?`". (FYI, unescaped, `?` has special meaning in a regex.)

---

However, you did not mention  what should happen if there are multiple `?`. The regex above will match until the last one.

If you want to match until the first,

```
s = s.replaceAll("/.*?(?=\\?)", "");
```

The extra `?` causes the repeated match to be "reluctant".

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` so no ``\\`` is needed before `/`. Also it seems that OP input is link so there cant be any second `?` in it, but I like the way you include this possibility in your answer :)

Comment: @Pshemo: "it seems". I guess so?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String s = "asdf/dfa/fds?adsf".replaceAll("/.*(?=\\?)", "");
```